# How much repetitions of virtual experiments are enough to be "statistically sure" about its findings?

Tags: statistics, netlogo, agent-based-modeling, behaviorspace

After reading [this article](http://www.openabm.org/book/3138/how-use-behavior-space) about BehaviourSpace in Netlogo in which the author stated that "[...] the model is stochastic, you need to run each parameter setting many times to be statistically sure about this", I was wondering how much repetitions are enough to be "statistically sure" about the findings in virtual experiments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can use the formula mentioned in the question here to establish confidence in a randomized (monte carlo) simulation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95779/required-number-of-simulations-for-monte-carlo-analysis